# Loop over dataframe rows and write functions with unknown parameters

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame that looks like the one below.

```
Index_1 Index_2 Constant Outcome
   1      3        5        1
   2      3        6        0
   1      4        7        1
```

I need to write an equation for each line in the data frame. These equations will eventually be multiplied together to define a likelihood function. I want to create something that looks like this:

```
Index_1 Index_2 Constant Outcome Equation
   1      3        5        1      m_1 - m_3 + 5 + e_1
   2      3        6        0      m_2 - m_3 + 6 + e_2
   1      4        7        1      m_1 - m_4 + 7 + e_3
```

I can get R to print out the equations I need using this code:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {
  mu_a <- (paste("m_",data$Index_1[row],sep=""))
  mu_b <- (paste("m_",data$Index_2[row],sep=""))
  e_it <- (paste("e_", row,sep=""))
  print(paste(mu_a, paste("-",paste(mu_b,paste("+",paste(tradeoffs$d_lnxy[row], paste("+", e_it), sep = " "), sep = " "), sep = " "), sep = " "), sep = " "))
}
```

However, it's cumbersome and I want each m_j and e_t to be an object because these are the parameters the maximum likelihood will estimate. I think I need to use apply, but I'm struggling to write the function I need.

Answer (score 2):

How about first adding an index like this:

```
data$Index <- row.names(data)
```

Then just create a pasted equation like this:

```
data$Equation <- with(data,paste0("m_", Index_1, " - m_", Index_2, " + ", Constant, " + e_", Index))
```

Your result:

```
 Index_1 Index_2 Constant Outcome Index Equation           
    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>              
1       1       3        5       1 1     m_1 - m_3 + 5 + e_1
2       2       3        6       0 2     m_2 - m_3 + 6 + e_2
3       1       4        7       1 3     m_1 - m_4 + 7 + e_3
```

If you need to reference each term in the equation separately, you can create any number of additional columns using the paste0() function above. I.e., you can create a column called "mu_a" and then do paste0("m_", data$Index1). Then you can perform vectorized operations using this column along with your other columns (each representing a term in your equation).

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. One follow-up question: will having the equations as characters create problems? (i.e. how can I multiply them together and have R treat the m's and e's as variables, rather than just characters)

Comment: For example, when I use ```data$likelihood_t <- pnorm(data$Equation)^(data$choice)+(1-pnorm(data$Equation))^(1-data$choice)``` to write the observation-level likelihood, I get this error: ```Error in pnorm(data$model) : 
  Non-numeric argument to mathematical function```

Comment: I'll adjust the answer in a minute. Is' tradeoffs' the name of your dataframe in the example above?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I've edited my comment so that I use "data" as the name of my dataframe.

Comment: You can't feed a character string to a call like 'pnorm' like you do with 'pnorm(data$Equation)'. R doesn't know how to calculate that. Instead, you need to feed it actual numbers. Are the columns in the 'data' dataframe being replaced with other values from another dataframe/dataset?

Comment: If the values you are using are in the "data" dataframe, you should just calculate a column that is the value of that equation (as a number), not as a string. Then you feed the result of that into your likelihood calculation

Comment: If your actual values that you want to feed into the likelihood calculation are referencing some other dataframe, you'll need to restructure things.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because I don't have "actual numbers." The characters ```m_1, m_2, m_3, and m_4``` represent variables with unknown values (which is why I need to write out a likelihood function and then maximize it with respect to ```m_1 - m_4 ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209591/discussion-between-mh765-and-hannah-solheim).

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop. You can just paste the variables together, i.e.

```
paste0('m_', df1$Index_1, ' - m_', df1$Index_2, ' + ', df1$Constant, ' + e_', seq(nrow(df1)))
#[1] "m_1 - m_3 + 5 + e_1" "m_2 - m_3 + 6 + e_2" "m_1 - m_4 + 7 + e_3"
```